# Replacing Celerybeat with Chronos

Tags: celery, scheduling, celerybeat

How mature is [Chronos](http://airbnb.github.io/chronos/)? Is it a viable alternative to scheduler like celery-beat?

Right now our scheduling implements a periodic "heartbeat" task that checks of "outstanding" events and fires them if they are overdue. We are using [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57)'s rrule for defining this.

We are looking at alternatives to this approach, and [Chronos](http://airbnb.github.io/chronos/) seems a very attactive alternative: 1) it would mitigate the necessity to use a heartbeat schedule task, 2) it supports RESTful submission of events with ISO8601 format, 3) has a useful interface for management, and 4) it scales.

The crucial requirement is that scheduling needs to be configurable on the fly from the Web Interface. This is why can't use celerybeat's built-in scheduling out of the box.

---

Are we going to shoot ourselves in the foot by switching over to Chronos?

Comment: Did you ever answer this question on your own?

Comment: @crowder: No. It was rather complicated to deploy, and it doesnt seem like it is widely adopted.

Comment: So what have you cobbled together for scheduling/dispatching for celery? Just using celery beat, on one node, with your fingers crossed?

Comment: @crowder: Yes, celery beat on a single node. It also happens to be the node that runs Celery's message broker (RabbitMQ) We have some external watchdogs to make sure it is running. We've been running this for close to 16 months now (with close to 5k scheduled messages a day) and have not had celery beat fail yet.

Answer (score 0):

[This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194975/how-to-dynamically-add-remove-periodic-tasks-to-celery-celerybeat) has solutions to your dynamic periodic task problem.  It's not the accepted answer at the moment:

```
 from djcelery.models import PeriodicTask, IntervalSchedule
 from datetime import datetime

 class TaskScheduler(models.Model):

     periodic_task = models.ForeignKey(PeriodicTask)

     @staticmethod
     def schedule_every(task_name, period, every, args=None, kwargs=None):
     """ schedules a task by name every "every" "period". So an example call would be:
          TaskScheduler('mycustomtask', 'seconds', 30, [1,2,3]) 
          that would schedule your custom task to run every 30 seconds with the arguments 1 ,2 and 3 passed to the actual task. 
     """
         permissible_periods = ['days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']
         if period not in permissible_periods:
             raise Exception('Invalid period specified')
         # create the periodic task and the interval
         ptask_name = "%s_%s" % (task_name, datetime.datetime.now()) # create some name for the period task
         interval_schedules = IntervalSchedule.objects.filter(period=period, every=every)
         if interval_schedules: # just check if interval schedules exist like that already and reuse em
             interval_schedule = interval_schedules[0]
         else: # create a brand new interval schedule
             interval_schedule = IntervalSchedule()
             interval_schedule.every = every # should check to make sure this is a positive int
             interval_schedule.period = period 
             interval_schedule.save()
         ptask = PeriodicTask(name=ptask_name, task=task_name, interval=interval_schedule)
         if args:
             ptask.args = args
         if kwargs:
             ptask.kwargs = kwargs
         ptask.save()
         return TaskScheduler.objects.create(periodic_task=ptask)

     def stop(self):
         """pauses the task"""
         ptask = self.periodic_task
         ptask.enabled = False
         ptask.save()

     def start(self):
         """starts the task"""
         ptask = self.periodic_task
         ptask.enabled = True
         ptask.save()

     def terminate(self):
         self.stop()
         ptask = self.periodic_task
         self.delete()
         ptask.delete()
```

I haven't used [djcelery](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/tree/master/djcelery) yet, but it supposedly has an admin interface for dynamic periodic tasks.