# Adding periodic tasks dynamically from flask app

Tags: flask, celery, django-celery, apscheduler

I have a flask web app deployed in heroku. I need to schedule a background task to be scheduled at a specific time. I have tried using the [apscheduler](https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/src/) module. While it allows to define periodic tasks easily adding them from your application at runtime is what I am looking for.

I tried sharing the same jobstores in apscheduler

```
import time

from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.shelve_store import ShelveJobStore

sched = Scheduler()
sched.add_jobstore(ShelveJobStore('jobstore.db'), 'shelve')

sched.start()
```

And from terminal I tried this,

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 12 2013, 12:00:47) 
[GCC 4.8.0 20130502 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
>>> sc = Scheduler()
>>> sc.add_jobstore('jobstore.db', 'shelve')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dhananjay/git/blast/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 168, in add_jobstore
    jobstore.load_jobs()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'load_jobs'
```

I have come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194975/how-to-dynamically-add-remove-periodic-tasks-to-celery-celerybeat), while looking for a celery based approach. It talks about the same problem from a django perspective but I can't get it to work with my app (I am completely oblivious to django)

Comment: The issue here is that in the first case you call `sched.add_jobstore` with an instance of `ShelveJobStore` as its first argument and in the second you call it with a string as the first argument.  Change your second example to use `ShelveJobStore` as well and things should just work.

Comment: A free Heroku instance will not allow background threads, not really mentioned here .. so no clue if thats the case.
Background threads will count towards cpu usage on a payed account, and can be expensive.. so evaluate if Heroku is the right place for a scheduled job, or if you can eliminate this by doing some clever engineering. Even then, you would as the answer suggests, use a background dyno

Answer (score -1):

When you tried running it from the terminal, you gave add_jobstore a string as the first parameter, instead of a job store. It expects a job store as the first parameter, [see the documentation for more info](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html?highlight=add_jobstore#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_jobstore).

As for scheduling background tasks in Heroku, I would recommend reading the [Worker Dynos, Background Jobs and Queueing](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) article on the matter.