# Add, modify, remove celery.schedules at run time

Tags: python, celery

is there a way to Add, modify, remove celery.schedules at run time. I need something that reads a db table periodically to know list of schedules.

Document says one can use `djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler` to achieve what I want, but not sure how to do it.

I read [How to dynamically add / remove periodic tasks to Celery (celerybeat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194975/how-to-dynamically-add-remove-periodic-tasks-to-celery-celerybeat), still not clear

Thanks for help

Comment: Anything changed on this since 2014?

Comment: Havent tried after that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you set in your app settings:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER='djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

`celery beat` proces checks django PeriodicTask model to see what task should be executed.

You can add / modify / remove those tasks by modifying it using django model:

```
from djcelery.models import PeriodicTask, CrontabSchedule

every_hours_crontab = CrontabSchedule(minute=0)
every_hours_crontab.save()

periodic_task = PeriodicTask(
    name='Call my task every hour',
    task='myproject.tasks.mytask',
    crontab=every_hours_crontab,
    args=json.dump([arg1, arg2]),
    kwargs=json.dump({'foo': 'bar'})
)
periodic_task.save()
```

You can also test various configuration of PeriodicTask using django admin panel:
`http://localhost:8000/admin/djcelery/crontabschedule/add/`
`http://localhost:8000/admin/djcelery/periodictask/`

Comment: What if I'm not using django?

Comment: Then you need to implement such functionality by yourself or using any other framework you have.