# Django/djcelery 1.8.2 AppRegistryNotReady: Translation infrastructure cannot be initialized

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat, djcelery

I am getting the following error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 164, in _add_installed_apps_translations
"The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.
```

I have a project which is not really a django app but a celery app. Therefore, I have not created a `wsgi.py` or `models.py` or any of the typical files created by `django-admin` when a project or app is started.

I only want to use `djcelery` to be able to create periodic tasks using the `djcelery.schedules.DatabaseScheduler` like specified here [Add, modify, remove celery.schedules at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740880/add-modify-remove-celery-schedules-at-run-time?lq=1) and here [How to dynamically add / remove periodic tasks to Celery (celerybeat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194975/how-to-dynamically-add-remove-periodic-tasks-to-celery-celerybeat)

The solution to the problem as given here ([AppRegistryNotReady, translation bug when deploying with uWSGI](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23146)) requires me to make changes to vassal.ini file. There is no vassal.ini file in my implementation.

I will briefly describe my proj -

```
proj
  apps.py
  tasks.py
  celeryconfig.py
  runproj.py
```

- apps.py

```py
    from celery import Celery
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'celeryconfig')
    myapp = Celery('myapp')
    myapp.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
    if __name__ == '__main__'
        myapp.worker_main('-B', '-S', 'djcelery.schedules.DatabaseScheduler')
```

- tasks.py

```py
    from apps import myapp
    @myapp.task(name='msgprinter')
    def msg_printer(msg):
        print msg
```

- runproj.py

```py
    from djcelery.models import PeriodicTask, IntervalSchedule
    intSch = IntervalSchedule(period='seconds', every=30)
    periodic_task = PeriodicTask(
      name = 'msg_printer_schedule',
      task = 'proj.tasks.msg_printer',
      interval = intSch,
      args=json.dump(['such wow']),
     )
    periodic_task.save()
```

- celeryconfig.py

```py
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json']
    BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest@localhost'
    CELERY_IMPORTS = ('proj.tasks')
    CELERY_QUEUES = [Queue('default', Exchange('default', type='direct'), routing_key='default')]

    #DJANGO SETTINGS
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djcelery',
    'mypp')

    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join('/home', 'test.db'),
        }
    }
```

Before I run the workers I created the required tables using the `django-admin migrate` command. I can see the tables in the `/home/test.db` database.

First I run the workers - `$python apps.py`
Then I save a schedule to the database to be executed repeatedly by celerybeat daemon - `$python runproj.py`

Comment: Take a look this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24793445/2036767

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: AppRegistryNotReady()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793351/django-appregistrynotready)

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in django documentation, if you run your django app as a standalone one, you should ensure all the steps of the [initialization process](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#initialization-process) to be done by yourself:

> setup()
>
> This function is called automatically:
>
> - When running an HTTP server via Django’s WSGI support.
> - When invoking a management command.
>
> It must be called explicitly in other cases, for instance in plain Python scripts.

In your case it would be is as simple as call `django.setup()`:

```
from celery import Celery
import django
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'celeryconfig')
myapp = Celery('myapp')
myapp.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

if __name__ == '__main__'
    django.setup()
    myapp.worker_main('-B', '-S', 'djcelery.schedules.DatabaseScheduler')
```

Also, your settings module (`celeryconfig.py`) should be treated as a python code, so you have to import all of the used objects (`Queue` and `Exchange` from `kombu` and the `os` module).

And contain django-required settings. Add a `SECRET_KEY` in your `celeryconfig.py` file:

```
from kombu import Exchange, Queue
import os


CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json']
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest@localhost'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('proj.tasks')
CELERY_QUEUES = [Queue('default', Exchange('default', type='direct'), routing_key='default')]

#DJANGO SETTINGS
SECRET_KEY = "YOUR_TOP_SECRET_KEY"

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'djcelery',
'mypp')

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join('/home', 'test.db'),
    }
}
```