# How to schedule job based on user given frequency using celery in django?

Tags: django, celery, amqp, django-celery

I have a django model which has `frequency` and `end_date` attributes, I'm required to perform a task related to that model at regular intervals of time i.e., the `frequency` until the `end_date` is reached. I used celery to perform the task for all the entries in the database which are not expired yet (i.e., `end_date` is not reached yet), How do I go about executing a particular task based on its frequency?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194975/how-to-dynamically-add-remove-periodic-tasks-to-celery-celerybeat. This might help you