# Celery schedule tasks based on user input

Tags: django, celery

I have a task which is supposed to be configurable as in when it should run, for eg. run task every 6 hours/12 hours/midnight. So, a user has three options to choose from and depending on the selection the task should be run. If it was a static configuration I know how to do it. I am using celery package and not djcelery.

Celery version : 3.1.23

Comment: How will user choose?

Comment: @MuhammadTahir I will be providing a UI where every job will have scheduling options

Comment: You will have to use djcelery as far as I know, see http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes.

Comment: This is probably how you can do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194975/how-to-dynamically-add-remove-periodic-tasks-to-celery-celerybeat

Comment: Isn't it possible only with celery?

Comment: No, as just using celery you cannot update schedule of periodic tasks. You will have to write your own code similar to djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler to do it with only celery.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir For now I am using redis as CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND right now, lets say I use django-celery i will have to change this setting to djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend. How would this affect my other tasks?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107821/discussion-between-muhammad-tahir-and-rajesh-yogeshwar).