# Reload celery beat config

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I'm using `celery` and `celery-beat` without Django and I have a task which needs to modify `celery-beat` schedule when run.

Now I have the following code (module called `celery_tasks`):

```
# __init__.py

from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

---

```
#celery.py

from celery import Celery

import config

celery_config = config.get_celery_config()

app = Celery(
    __name__,
    include=[
        'celery_tasks.tasks',
    ],
)

app.conf.update(celery_config)
```

---

```
# tasks.py

from celery_tasks import celery_app
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def start_game():

    celery_app.conf.beat_schedule = {
        'process_round': {
            'task': 'celery_tasks.tasks.process_round',
            'schedule': 5,
        },
    }
```

---

I start `celery` with the following command:

```
celery worker -A celery_tasks -E -l info --beat
```

`start_game` executes and exists normally, but beat `process_round` task never runs.

How can I force-reload beat schedule (restarting all workers doesn't seem as a good idea)?

Comment: why do you need to reload celery beat ?

Comment: @NakulNarayanan, I need to change celery beat schedule in another task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem with normal celery backend when you start the celerybeat process. it will create a config file and write all tasks and schedules in to that file 
 
so it cannot change dynamically
you can use the package
`celerybeat-sqlalchemy-scheduler` so you can edit schedule on DB itself so that celerybeat will pickup the new schedule from DB itself

also there is another package `celery-redbeat` which using redis-server as backend

you can refer this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194975/how-to-dynamically-add-remove-periodic-tasks-to-celery-celerybeat) also

Answer (score 0):

Using schedule config also seems bad idea. What if initially process_round task will be active and check if game is not started task just do nothing.