# Modifying Celery beat schedule shelve database

Tags: python, celery, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I'm trying to schedule periodic tasks at runtime in Celery.

Here is an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194975/how-to-dynamically-add-remove-periodic-tasks-to-celery-celerybeat) that is relevant. [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55603127/4997836) in that question mentions that it is now possible to add tasks during runtime since Celery version 4.1.0 (I'm using 4.3.0) but I am not able to achieve that.

I'm modifying the shelve database while the Celery beat is running (or even when it's not running). Here's the code doing that:

```py
import shelve
from celery.beat import ScheduleEntry
from celery.schedules import schedule

s = schedule(5, app=app)
entry = ScheduleEntry("Test Task", "proj.tasks.my_task", args=("arg1", "arg2"), schedule=s)
db = shelve.open("celerybeat-schedule", writeback=True)
db["entries"]["Test Task"] = entry
db.close()
```

This is stored in the shelve file successfully. Here's the `entries` field that shelve file:

```
{'Test Task': <ScheduleEntry: Test Task proj.tasks.my_task('arg1', 'arg2') <freq: 5.00 seconds>}
```

But as soon as the celery beat starts, it over-writes this file and makes `entries` field an empty `dict`. Am I missing something? Or this is not possible without using Django or similar scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this is still not possible. I switched over to using [celerybeat-mongo](https://github.com/zmap/celerybeat-mongo) which conveniently stores all the schedules in a Mongo collection and also loads from the same collection that might have been inserted by some other process.